# Javascript won't get value from textbox issue, why not?

Tags: javascript, input, textbox

I have this code:

```
<script>
    function getAge() {
        var birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdatebox").value;
        document.getElementById("agecomputed").innerHTML = calculateAge2(birthdate);

    }
</script>
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="birthdatebox" />
        <button onclick="getAge()" name="birthdatebutton">Get Your Age</button>
        <div id="agecomputed"></div>
```

It should return the calculated value. Nothing happens. Just doesn't work.
Please help.

UPDATE:
I have a reference to the js file, which contains the calculateAge2 function and it does work when I pass a number directly instead of birthdate variable.

Comment: Where do you define `calculateAge2` function? What does it do? Note that default value for the `button` element's `type` attribute  is `submit` which submits the form (if any).

Comment: No, it doesnt work with the submit form either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `id` attribute to your `<input>` element, like this...

```
<input type="text" name="birthdatebox" id="birthdatebox" />
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I will mark it as an answer as soon the site allows me to do it.